# Is there a recommended way to distribute iOS apps to testers prior to publishing on the app store?

Tags: nativescript

I need to distribute my apps to testers prior to submitting them to the store(s).  Nativescript builds an apk file that is easily distributed to Android testers.  Is TestFlight the recommended way to distribute iOS apps? And should I use the xcode project file to build the app in Xcode in order to submit it to TestFlight.  That method seems counter intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ideally you would use TestFlight. It's also a perfect way for you to test your distribution build/signing etc since you would upload the exact same build that will end up on the App Store. In fact, if your testing goes well with your users, you can submit the same build that you've already uploaded for TestFlight to the reviewers for the App Store, you don't even need to upload a new build.

Answer (score 1):

As @Dave Wood mentioned, yes, TestFlight should be the way to go forward as you do not need to re-build the app to submit for review to Apple.
Answer to your next question `should I use the xcode project file to build the app in Xcode` -
No
You can use the below commands to build and publish app to Apple store.
From the root folder of your app

`tns build ios --release --for-device --bundle <Your Provision Profile>`

this will show the path where it has created the .ipa file, then 
`tns publish ios --ipa <.ipa file>`

this will ask your Apple ID and [App Specific password](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204397) and will process the actual App based on your appid mentioned in your package.json.

You can change the app version and App name in info.plist inside App Resources->ios folder.

Comment: I followed these instructions, but the build command doesn't work- instead it gives this error, "Failed to find mobile provision with UUID or Name:"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.  I realized this was the answer after I posted the question.  I'm new to NativeScript, but not to iOS development.  It occurred to me that once the app is uploaded to App Store Connect, I still control the activities of either posting or setting up TestFlight.  Thank you.

Comment: Hi Brusie. You're new here, so here are a couple of notes for you: a) don't post an answer that's a response to another answer. This should be a comment, either on a specific answer, or even to the original question. b) upvote any answer you feel was helpful, c) once you have a correct answer, please mark it as so, then the question shows up as answered in searches etc. Thanks, I hope you enjoy your time here!